# Show date for entries in Live Bookmark

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, rss, feed

I use Firefox's "Live Bookmark" to subscribe to an RSS feed. This works fine, however if I click the Bookmark, I just get a list of recents posts with their titles. I would like to see the post date alongside the title, to get a quick impression of what's recent.

Is there a way to configure Live Bookmarks to show the date for each post? Or is there an addon which will do this? Basically, I'd like to get a list of recent posts, each with title + date, or something similar (such as posts grouped by date).

Note:

I manually downloaded the XML from the feed, and saw that it contains elements `<updated>` and `<published>` with a date, so the feed does contain the information I want.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [Bugzilla entry for that feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=268862) which was resolved as "won't fix", so Firefox cannot currently do it and will probably not learn it either. I'm also not aware of an add-on capable of displaying the date / time along with Life Bookmarks, but I believe this would be a perfect addition to the [LifeClick add-on](http://projects.protej.com/index.php?/liveclick/home/). I'll suggest to add that feature to the authors.